# Error "incomplete type MD5_CONTEXT" with MariaDB 10.2 and Openssl 1.1.0e

Tags: openssl, mariadb, centos7, rocksdb

I can't build MariaDB 10.2 with RocksDB enabled, in CentOS 7.

It has the following compile error:

```
/root/mariadb-10.2/mysys_ssl/my_md5.cc: In function ‘void md5_result(MD5_CONTEXT*, uchar*)’: /root/mariadb-10.2/mysys_ssl/my_md5.cc:86:29: error: ‘EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup’ was not declared in this scope    EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(context);
                             ^ /root/mariadb-10.2/mysys_ssl/my_md5.cc: In function ‘void my_md5(uchar*, const char*, size_t)’: /root/mariadb-10.2/mysys_ssl/my_md5.cc:102:15: error: aggregate ‘MD5_CONTEXT md5_context’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined    MD5_CONTEXT md5_context;
               ^ /root/mariadb-10.2/mysys_ssl/my_md5.cc: In function ‘void my_md5_multi(uchar*, ...)’: /root/mariadb-10.2/mysys_ssl/my_md5.cc:127:15: error: aggregate ‘MD5_CONTEXT md5_context’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined    MD5_CONTEXT md5_context;
               ^ /root/mariadb-10.2/mysys_ssl/my_md5.cc: In function ‘size_t my_md5_context_size()’: /root/mariadb-10.2/mysys_ssl/my_md5.cc:140:28: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘MD5_CONTEXT {aka evp_md_ctx_st}’    return sizeof(MD5_CONTEXT);
                            ^ make[2]: *** [mysys_ssl/CMakeFiles/mysys_ssl.dir/my_md5.cc.o] Error 1 make[1]: *** [mysys_ssl/CMakeFiles/mysys_ssl.dir/all] Error 2
```

Here is the commands I used to build it:

> yum install g++ cmake libbz2-dev libaio-dev bison zlib1g-dev libsnappy-dev  libgflags-dev libreadline6-dev libncurses5-dev libssl-dev liblz4-dev gdb git

```
git clone https://github.com/MariaDB/server.git mariadb-10.2
git checkout bb-10.2-mariarocks
git submodule init  git submodule update

cmake -DCURSES_LIBRARY=/usr/lib64/libncurses -DCURSES_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include . 
make -j10
```

I guess it's the OpenSSL version problem, maybe MariaDB supports older OpenSSL version only.

So, anyone knows how to fix it?

my versions:

- OpenSSL 1.1.0e  16 Feb 2017
- g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623

Thanks,

Comment: Errors relating to *" ... invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ..."* often indicates one of the programs or libraries is ***not*** OpenSSL 1.1.0 aware. Use OpenSSL 1.0.2 instead. You may need to enable Weak ciphers to get MD5. Also see [OpenSSL 1.1.0 Compatibility and Changes](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_1.1.0_Changes) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: but I have to use latest/newer OpenSSL version.

Comment: Then you are mostly screwed if the projects are *not* OpenSSL 1.1.0 aware. [OpenSSH is screwing me](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/pull/48) because I need ChaCha/Poly1305 (and TLS 1.3. in the future), but OpenSSH only supports OpenSSL 1.0.2 and below. Side-by-side installations of OpenSSL are mostly broken on Unix and Linux, so I have not been able to work around it.

Answer (score 1):

Support for OpenSSL 1.1 [was added](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10332) in MariaDB 10.2.6, which as of today *(May 17, 2017)* has not been released yet, but is expected to be very soon.

Since you are taking source code from github, you can try it now already, but you shouldn't be using `bb-10.2-mariarocks` tree -- while it might have some newest experimental changes in RocksDB (or not), it is likely to be outdated in any other way. Please use `10.2` branch instead, it has RocksDB as well.

Comment: I changed to use 10.2 now, but it had different compile errors:

CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/secure/openssl.c.o: In function `ma_tls_start':
/root/mariadb-10.2/libmariadb/libmariadb/secure/openssl.c:299: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
CMakeFiles/mariadb_obj.dir/secure/openssl.c.o: In function `ma_tls_init':
/root/mariadb-10.2/libmariadb/libmariadb/secure/openssl.c:488: undefined reference to `TLS_client_method'

Comment: I'll do some guessing. If you've installed OpenSSL 1.1.0 into `/usr/local/lib64`, while `/usr/lib64` still has 1.0.1, your build gets confused. Try to re-run `cmake` with explicit paths to `SSL` and `CRYPTO`, like `cmake . -DOPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib64/libssl.so -DOPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib64/libcrypto.so`, and then `make` again.

Comment: I tried that. Better! but still some other error:

make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib64/libncurses', needed by `client/mysql'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

Comment: btw, I have  1.0.1e in /usr/lib64/

Comment: 1.1 in /usr/local/lib64/

Comment: and I used 1.1 (for my last try)
like this  -DOPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib64/libssl.so

Comment: The last one about ncurses looks weird, and unrelated, more like a configuration error (it came up with `make /usr/local/lib64`?!). I'd suggest to remove `CMakeCache.txt`, maybe even `make clean` to be safe (or `git clean -dfx`), then re-run the whole `cmake <all options together>` command, and then make.  And if it goes bad again, please paste the `cmake` command that you've run.

Comment: Oh, I've got passed that error, if I specify the version, like -DCURSES_LIBRARY=/usr/lib64/libncurses.so.5

Comment: But....yet another error:

Linking CXX executable mysql
/usr/bin/ld: ../extra/readline/libreadline.a(terminal.c.o): undefined reference to symbol 'UP'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'UP' is defined in DSO /lib64/libtinfo.so.5 so try adding it to the linker command line
/lib64/libtinfo.so.5: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Since you're already on the route of giving cmake paths to libraries, you can explore `WITH_READLINE`, `READLINE_INCLUDE_DIR` and `READLINE_LIBRARY` cmake options and  see which combination works for you.

Comment: passed that error. Now, another error @.@".....
/root/mariadb-10.2/client/mysql.cc:100:24: error: variable or field ‘my_vidattr’ declared void
 static void my_vidattr(chtype attrs)
                        ^
/root/mariadb-10.2/client/mysql.cc:100:24: error: ‘chtype’ was not declared in this scope
/root/mariadb-10.2/client/mysql.cc: In function ‘int com_status(String*, char*)’:
/root/mariadb-10.2/client/mysql.cc:4753:16: error: ‘A_BOLD’ was not declared in this scope
     my_vidattr(A_BOLD);

Comment: Actually, I just want RocksDB engine enabled. But the version I've got (10.2.5) doesn't have it.., that's why I wanted to build it from source

Comment: RocksDB is in 10.2.5, it comes as a separate package, e.g. `MariaDB-10.2.5-centos7-x86_64-rocksdb-engine.rpm`. For the build problems -- you're using a customized installation of CentOS, that's probably why it's so difficult. You can see build logs for CentOS 7 from the build system, e.g. at https://buildbot.askmonty.org/buildbot/builders/kvm-rpm-centos7-amd64/builds/3926/steps/compile/logs/stdio , it's fairly smooth: