# Which lib to use? libmariadbclient or libmysqlclient?

Tags: mariadb

For some unknown reason, my libmysqlclient.a disappeared in my CentOS 7.
My program then got linker error, saying cannot find libmysqlclient.

And then I discovered that my mysql-devel package is gone:

```
yum info mysql-devel
yum install mysql-devel
```

Here is the response:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: repo.virtualhosting.hk
 * epel: mirror.pregi.net
 * extras: repo.virtualhosting.hk
 * updates: repo.virtualhosting.hk
Package MariaDB-devel-10.2.5-1.el7.centos.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

So I think maybe I should use libmariadbclient instead, but when I link my program with libmariadbclient, it had linking errors:

```
/usr/lib64//libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_start':
(.text+0x191): undefined reference to `CRYPTO_num_locks'
/usr/lib64//libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_start':
(.text+0x1aa): undefined reference to `CRYPTO_THREADID_set_callback'
/usr/lib64//libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_start':
(.text+0x1b6): undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_locking_callback'
/usr/lib64//libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_start':
(.text+0x1bb): undefined reference to `SSL_library_init'
/usr/lib64//libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_start':
(.text+0x1c7): undefined reference to `SSL_load_error_strings'
/usr/lib64//libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_start':
(.text+0x1cc): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf'
/usr/lib64//libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_end':
(.text+0x2b4): undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_locking_callback'
/usr/lib64//libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_end':
(.text+0x2bb): undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_id_callback'
/usr/lib64//libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_end':
(.text+0x2df): undefined reference to `CRYPTO_num_locks'
/usr/lib64//libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_end':
(.text+0x340): undefined reference to `EVP_cleanup'
/usr/lib64//libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_end':
(.text+0x345): undefined reference to `CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data'
/usr/lib64//libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_end':
(.text+0x34a): undefined reference to `ERR_free_strings'
/usr/lib64//libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_end':
(.text+0x351): undefined reference to `CONF_modules_free'
/usr/lib64//libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_init':
(.text+0x3e1): undefined reference to `SSLv23_client_method'
/usr/lib64//libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `my_cb_threadid':
(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `CRYPTO_THREADID_set_numeric'
/usr/lib64//libmariadbclient.a(ma_compress.c.o): In function `_mariadb_compress_alloc':
(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `compress'
/usr/lib64//libmariadbclient.a(ma_compress.c.o): In function `_mariadb_uncompress':
(.text+0x191): undefined reference to `uncompress'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've been using libmysqlclient to connect with my MariaDB 10.1, and have recently been trying to build it from source, but failed due to problems with OpenSSL 1.1 version. Here you see my another post for it:

[Error "incomplete type MD5_CONTEXT" with MariaDB 10.2 and Openssl 1.1.0e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012487/error-incomplete-type-md5-context-with-mariadb-10-2-and-openssl-1-1-0e?noredirect=1#comment75087110_44012487)

So I'm confused why mysqlclient.a disappeared and which lib I should use.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem when tried to compile my program with "**-lmariadbclient**" (after apt-get update **-lmysqlclient** stopped working).
The Makefile I used was:

```
g++ -std=c++11 *.cpp ../common/*.cpp ../common/*.c -o myprogram -I.. -ldl -Wstack-protector -fstack-protector-all -pthread -ggdb -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lmariadbclient -Wwrite-strings  -fPIC
```

I read that commands "**-lssl -lcrypto -lz**" must be added to fix those errors, but I put them in the wrong place (before lmariadbclient). When I added them after "**-lmariadbclient**" I was finally able to compile my program:

```
g++ -std=c++11 *.cpp ../common/*.cpp ../common/*.c -o myprogram -I.. -ldl -Wstack-protector -fstack-protector-all -pthread -ggdb -lmariadbclient -Wwrite-strings -lssl -lcrypto -lz -fPIC
```

**UPDATE 22.07.2017:**

I recently tried to compile my program on the new Linux Mint 18.2. Unfortunately I was getting the same compilation errors, and I was unable to fix it with the old method:

MariaDB version:

```
 mysql --version
 mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.7-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

Compile errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_start':
(.text+0x189): undefined reference to `CRYPTO_num_locks'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_start':
(.text+0x1a4): undefined reference to `CRYPTO_THREADID_set_callback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_start':
(.text+0x1b0): undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_locking_callback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_start':
(.text+0x1b5): undefined reference to `SSL_library_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_start':
(.text+0x1c1): undefined reference to `SSL_load_error_strings'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_start':
(.text+0x1c6): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_end':
(.text+0x2a4): undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_locking_callback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_end':
(.text+0x2ab): undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_id_callback'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_end':
(.text+0x2cf): undefined reference to `CRYPTO_num_locks'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_end':
(.text+0x330): undefined reference to `EVP_cleanup'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_end':
(.text+0x335): undefined reference to `CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_end':
(.text+0x33a): undefined reference to `ERR_free_strings'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_end':
(.text+0x33f): undefined reference to `CONF_modules_free'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `ma_tls_init':
(.text+0x3c1): undefined reference to `SSLv23_client_method'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadbclient.a(openssl.c.o): In function `my_cb_threadid':
(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `CRYPTO_THREADID_set_numeric'
```

I managed to fix it by changing "**-lmariadbclient**" to: "**-lmariadb**". After that I was able to compile my program with no errors. I'm not sure if this solution will work for everyone, but worth to try :)

My final Makefile is:

```
g++ -std=c++11 *.cpp ../common/*.cpp ../common/*.c -o myprogram -I.. -ldl -Wstack-protector -fstack-protector-all -pthread -ggdb -lmariadb -Wwrite-strings -lssl -lcrypto -lz -fPIC
```

Good luck!

Comment: I tried to put -lmariadbclient before anything, but still have those link errors.

Comment: Kenji, did you install all dependencies? I think it was: "libssl-dev", "openssl-devel" and "libz-dev".

Comment: Mona, I cannot install/find libssl-dev, but I'm sure I installed openssl-devel and libz-dev

Comment: and something strange that, the system shows that I installed openssl-devel-1.0.1e-60.el7_3.1.x86_64, but I manually installed 1.1.0e, newer version. I'm using 1.1.0e version, and I hope MariaDB also. Maybe version mismatch is the problem? How to force MariaDB to use the newer openssl version?

Comment: update: I did not link with libz, so forget about the compress/uncompress undefined references. now only the ssl related ones bother me

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help much since I also often experience linking problems and always looking for answers by google. I can only confirm that "libssl-dev" works for me (apt-get install libssl-dev - The following packages will be upgraded: libssl-dev libssl1.0.0 libssl1.0.0:i386). About libz: I tried to compile without "-lz" but I get error: "In function `_mariadb_uncompress': undefined reference to `uncompress'".

Comment: @kchkg I updated my answer. After I upgraded to Linux Mint 18.2 I was unable to compile my program. Seems like changing "-lmariadbclient" to "-lmariadb" fixed it!