# libmariadbclient-dev install error: Depends: libmariadbclient18

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mariadb

I'm trying to install mysqclient, but I'm getting an error when trying 'apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev' in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Python 3.7.0.

How can I make this work? Thanks.

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev
Reading package lists... Done   
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libmariadbclient-dev : Depends: libmariadbclient18 (= 1:10.1.29-6) but 1:10.3.7+maria~bionic is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installing an older version, works:

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient18=1:10.1.29-6
sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient18-dev=1:10.1.29-6
pip3.7 install mysqlclient
```

Update 07/12/2018:
Today, I installed MariaDB 10.3.8 as shown below (in a clean system) and  libmariadbclient18 installed without complaining:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xF1656F24C74CD1D8
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,arm64,ppc64el] http://sfo1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.3/ubuntu bionic main'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mariadb-server
sudo apt install mariadb-client
sudo apt install libmariadb-dev
sudo apt install libmariadb-dev-compat
sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient18
```

I don't know whether having installed libmariadb-dv and libmariadv-dev-compat helped.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same problem and this solution worked. Does it matter that we use an older version of this thing?

Comment: It seems to work fine but I need to test it more time. I'll update this case if  I observe some issue.

Comment: One thing I noticed, regarding: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44401943/2517973
I had to change the "-lmariadb" to "-lmariadbclient" again :) But except that it seems to compile fine.

Comment: By the way. Maybe "libmariadbclient-dev" is not needed anymore? I installed: "libmariadb-dev" and "libmariadb-dev-compat". the "compat" package fixed "include" errors during compilation. I just use "-lmariadb" in Makefile.

Comment: @Mona :  I had to install MariaDB in clean system, just tried with "libmariadb-dev" a and "libmariadb-dev-compat", but they weren't sufficient because my application still complains: import MySQLdb  import _mysql ImportError: libmariadbclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

I also needed the package `libmariadbclient-dev` (or sometimes `libmysqlclient-dev`) in the past, otherwise the Python pip package [mysqlclient](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient) wouldn't install.

Then I ran into this error too. And I tried installing `libmariadb-dev` instead, and that worked. `pip install mysqlclient` works with this package too for me.

Hope that helps anyone.